# Comparing 2 files in c linux fgets

Tags: c, linux

I need to compare 2 files and return 1 if they are same or 0 if not, but function always return 0. I have no idea why. Maybe you know diferent function that can do this.

```
int compare(char *file_1, char *file_2)
{
    FILE *data_1 = fopen(file_1,"r");
    FILE *data_2 = fopen(file_2,"r");
    char line1[1000];
    char line2[1000];
    while(fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), data_1)&&fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), data_2)){
        if(strcmp(line1,line2)==0){
          fclose(data_1);
          fclose(data_2);
          return 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(data_1);
    fclose(data_2);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: why it is not the case ? fgets always put the \0

Comment: @G.M. get a cofee with P.W ^^

Comment: the `while` expression should probably be using `||` not `&&` since if one file is shorter than the other, the `while` loop will end and it'll return 1.

Comment: @ChrisTurner yes, this is my second remark of my answer ;-)

Comment: If the first lines match and the second doesn't, your program will still return 0.

Comment: @Don.Kielon l edited my answer to add a proposal

Comment: Why don't you compute the md5 hash (e.g. using openssl/md5.h ). If the hashes are equal you know that the files are equal.

Comment: @schorsch312 for me if the md5 are different the files are different, if they are equal we don't know if the files are equals or different, a md5 cannot cover all the content of a file, else that means the md5 is the reversible compression of the file

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Don Kielon Rolled edit back, else your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp(line1,line2)==0` means *line1* and *line2* are **equals**, your code supposes they are different

There is an other error, if a file is starts with the content of the other you consider the files are equals (supposing you corrected the *strcmp*)

---

I encourage you to check the result of the *fopen* in case at least one of them does not exist / cannot be open

---

a solution can be :

```
int compare(char *file_1, char *file_2)
{
  FILE *fp1 = fopen(file_1,"r");

  if (fp1 == 0)
    return 0;

  FILE *fp2 = fopen(file_2,"r");

  if (fp2 == 0) {
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
  }

  char line1[1000];
  char line2[1000];
  char * r1, * r2;
  int result;

  for (;;) {
    r1 = fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), fp1);
    r2 = fgets(line2, sizeof(line2), fp2);

    if ((r1 == 0) || (r2 == 0)) {
      result = (r1 == r2);
      break;
    }

    if (strcmp(line1,line2) != 0) {
      result = 0;
      break;
    }
  }

  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);

  return result;
}
```

Comment: it always return 0

Comment: In one program i get always 1 in other always 0

Comment: I changed again my definition, sorry. That one works in all cases

Comment: @bruno Why would you use `return (r1 == r2);`?

Comment: @Michi I do to take into account the fact the file may not have the same size but have the same start, so r1 == 0 but r2 != 0 or the reverse

Comment: You should report what exactly are you returning. There are two `return 0;` in your code.

Comment: it returns 1 when the files have the same content, 0 if at least one file cannot be open or if their content are not equal

Comment: How can we know which `fp` returns `0`? By the way [Your Code](https://pastebin.com/raw/d2HFYYmZ) The way is designed, if [File_1 and File_2 has the following content](https://pastebin.com/raw/xPrQ06Em) Then Works [Like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/rzathdA8).

Comment: The code fails to compare correctly when a file  contain a _null characters_ due to use of `strcmp()`.

Comment: @chux You are right, I supposed it is text files, the _fgets_ is also not a good choice for a non text file.

Comment: C does not require text files to not have _null characters_ - even so, there are uncommon in classical ASCII text files. Note: `(char) 0` is very common in UTF-16 text files.    Perhaps Linux has requirements about _null characters_ and text files?

Comment: @chux I am pretty sure you understand what I mean about text file ;-) Anyway it is easy to change the definition to be compatible with any files, do you think it is better to do ?

Comment: @bruno Using `fread()`, IMO, makes better sense as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114329/2410359).  Hard to say what folks think as better sometimes: Clear short code that well handles the common cases or   code to also handle many outlying cases.  Your call.

Answer (score 1):

you can compare files char by char (or byte by byte) to get faster result in case then files are not equal:

```
int compare(char *file_1, char *file_2)
{
    FILE *data_1 = fopen(file_1,"r");
    FILE *data_2 = fopen(file_2,"r");
    int ch1, ch2;
    for (;;) {
        ch1 = getc(data_1); 
        ch2 = getc(data_2); 

        if ((ch1 != ch2) || (ch1 == EOF)) break;
    }

    fclose(data_1);
    fclose(data_2);

    return (ch1 == ch2);
}
```

Comment: read the files char by char is very expensive, slower than to read block by block

Comment: ch1 and ch2 must not be char but int, currently you cannot detect EOF

Comment: if the files are different you do not close the file

Comment: you also have 2 times `if (ch1 != ch2) return 0`

Comment: @bruno Yes char by char is slower than block by block, but it is not very expensive (`fgetc` typically does buffered reads). For simpler code, the tradeoff may be worth it.

Comment: @bruno fixed return by break and file closing

Comment: @myxaxa consider these two consecutives lines : `if (ch1 != ch2) break; if (ch1 == EOF || ch2 == EOF) break;` , if the first test is false that means that ch1 == ch2, so it is useless to check both ch1 and ch2 equal  EOF. Can be `if ((ch1 != ch2) || (ch1 == EOF)) break;`

Comment: @myxaxa you can also simplify `if (ch1 != ch2) return 0; return 1;` to be just `return (ch1 == ch2);`

Comment: @myxaxa again, do not forget to change ch1 and ch2 to be int rather than char

Comment: Just a remark : because you do not check what _fopen_ returns when the two files cannot be read (for instance they do not exist) you return 1. I preferred to return 0, to return 1 only when all is ok and the files are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Here are to solutions, one char by char read/comparisons (Inspired by the answer from myxaxa, but with bugfixes) And another block by block read/comparisons. Error checking has been skipped due to laziness, but a robust implementation MUST HAVE ERROR CHECKING. (See comments)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int equal = 1;

    // TODO: check argc == 3

    FILE *data_1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *data_2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");

    // TODO: check data_1 and data_2 !=NULL

    for (;;)
      {
        int ch1, ch2;
        ch1 = fgetc(data_1); 
        ch2 = fgetc(data_2); 

        if (ch1 != ch2)
         { 
           equal = 0;
           break;
         }
        // We only need to test ch1, because at this point ch1 == ch2;   
        if (ch1 == EOF)
          break;
      }

    // TODO: check for read errors in data_1 and data_2 using ferror

    fclose(data_1);
    fclose(data_2);

    if (equal)
      printf("equal\n");
    else
      printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Second solution using block reads/comparisons:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 4096

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int equal = 1;

    // TODO: check argc == 3

    FILE *data_1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *data_2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");

    // TODO: check data_1 and data_2 !=NULL

    for (;;)
      {
        char b1[BUFFSIZE];
        char b2[BUFFSIZE];

        size_t r1 = fread(b1, 1, BUFFSIZE, data_1); 
        size_t r2 = fread(b2, 1, BUFFSIZE, data_2);

        if (r1 != r2)
          {
            equal = 0;
            break;
          }

        // We only need to test r1, because at this point r1 == r2;   
        if (r1 == 0)
          break;
        if (memcmp(b1, b2, r1) != 0)
          { 
            equal = 0;
            break;
          }
      }

    // TODO: check for read errors in data_1 and data_2 using ferror 

    fclose(data_1);
    fclose(data_2);

    if (equal)
      printf("equal\n");
    else
      printf("not equal\n");
}
```

Runtimes for char by char reads/comparisons on a 840Mb file compared with itself:

```
real    0m5.158s
user    0m4.880s
sys     0m0.277s
```

... and for block by block on the same file:

```
real    0m0.353s
user    0m0.083s
sys     0m0.270s
```

Both test did multiple runs to ensure file was already cached

Comment: do the check with 2 files with various first chars :)

Comment: I did that, but the result was boring. Essentially the same runtime as `/bin/true`

Answer (score 1):

Other issues concerning comparing files not covered in answers yet

**File data with `'\0'`**

Should a file contain a *null character*,  `fgets()` will read that character like any other non-end-of-line character.  Then a following `strcmp()` will **not** compare all the line that was read.  Better to use `fread()/memcmp()` to avoid this short-coming.

**Comparing as text or binary?**

Opening the file with `"r"` as in `fopen(file_1,"r")` allows various translations: end-of-line, end-of-file, byte-order marks.

Opening with `"r"` makes sense to compare as *text*.  Otherwise, open the file in *binary* mode `"rb"`.  Use `fread()` in either case.

A line of text with `"\r\n"` in one file and a line of text with `"\n"` in another file can compare equal in *text* mode, but differ in *binary* mode.

As post is tagged [linux] though, no translations are expected in *text* mode.

**Non-comparable**

During readings an input error may occur rendering the compare moot.

---

Sample compare code

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define FILE_COMPARE_N 1024

// 1: match
// 0: mis-match
// -1: failure
int stream_compare(FILE *f1, FILE *f2) {
  unsigned char buf1[FILE_COMPARE_N];
  unsigned char buf2[FILE_COMPARE_N];
  size_t l1, l2;
  do {
    l1 = fread(buf1, sizeof buf1[0], FILE_COMPARE_N, f1);
    if (ferror(f1))
      return -1;

    l2 = fread(buf2, sizeof buf2[0], FILE_COMPARE_N, f2);
    if (ferror(f2))
      return -1;

    if (l1 != l2 || memcmp(buf1, buf2, l1) != 0)
      return 0; // mis-match

  } while (l1);
  return 1; //match
}

int file_compare(const char *name1, const char *name2, bool as_text) {
  FILE *f1 = fopen(name1, as_text ? "rb" : "r");
  if (f1 == NULL)
    return -1;

  FILE *f2 = fopen(name2, as_text ? "rb" : "r");
  if (f2 == NULL) {
    fclose(f1);
    return -1;
  }

  int compare = stream_compare(f1, f2);

  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);
  return compare;
}
```

Comment: The "text vs. binary" mode is only an issue on obscure platforms, like Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try reading whole file in one go, the loop will run until whole of the file is read and If it matches once, it will always going to return 0.
Get the file size something like this and use malloc and read>

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: _reading whole file in one go_ :  this is a **bad** solution, you loose time reading all even you can detect before they are different, and if the files are huge you may not have enough memory to read them

Answer (score 0):

Well, if those files are not to big, a good approach will be like this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void fileExistence( const char *fileName );
char *readFile( const char *const fileName  );
size_t getFileSize ( FILE *const file );

int main ( void )
{
    const char *const file_1 = "file1.txt";
    const char *const file_2 = "file2.txt";

    char *const getFile_01 = readFile( file_1 );
    char *const getFile_02 = readFile( file_2 );

    if (strcmp( getFile_01, getFile_02 ) == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Files are the same\n" );
    }else
    {
        printf( "Files are not the same\n" );
    }

    free( getFile_01 );
    free( getFile_02 );

    return 0;
}

char *readFile( const char *const fName )
{
    fileExistence( fName );
    size_t size, length;
    char *buffer;
    FILE *file = fopen ( fName , "rb" );
    if ( file == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Can't open output file %s!\n", fName );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    length = getFileSize( file );
    if ( length == 0 )
    {
        printf( "Error, getFileSize()\n" );
    }

    buffer = malloc( length + 1 );
    if ( buffer == NULL ){
        printf( "Error, malloc().\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    size = fread ( buffer , 1 , length, file );
    if ( size != length ){
        printf( "Error, fread().\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    buffer[length] = '\0';
    fclose ( file );
    return buffer;
}

size_t getFileSize ( FILE *const file )
{
    int fsk = fseek ( file , 0 , SEEK_END );
    if ( fsk == -1 )
    {
        printf( "Error, fseek()\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    long tel = ftell( file );

    if ( tel < 0 || (unsigned long) tel >= SIZE_MAX )
    {
        printf( "Error, ftell()\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    fsk = fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_SET );
    if ( fsk == -1 )
    {
        printf( "Error, fseek()\n" );
        return 0;
    }
    return ( size_t )tel;
}

void fileExistence( const char *const fileName )
{
    if( access(fileName, F_OK ) )
    {
        printf("The File %s\t not Found\n",fileName);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( access(fileName, R_OK ) )
    {
        printf("The File %s\t cannot be readed\n",fileName);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( access( fileName, W_OK ) )
    {
        printf("The File %s\t it cannot be Edited\n",fileName);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

Where you read both files and save them in two buffers and use `strcmp()` to compare both them.

If you need compare files without capitalization you can use `strcasecmp()` function which is found in `strings.h`

Comment: why do you use strcasecmp ? doing that you are not case sensitive

Comment: no, I did because your solution doesn't work if you cannot read all, there is no reason to be blocked by that kind of problem

Comment: for instance the case producing `fputs ("Memory error",stderr);`

Comment: To accomplish that I made those changes. Thank you.

Comment: Why use `size_t length` to save result from `long ftell(file)`?  1) Code misses the error check and 2) a `(size_t)ftell (file)`  cast may lose information.

Comment: Something like `long tel = ftell(file); if (tel < 0 || tel >= SIZE_MAX) error(); else length = (size_t) tel;` may help.

Comment: Yes, you right. So and so I need a cast to size_t :D. But you right because there is no `-1` possible. Any way there will be a warning reported like `comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘long int’ and ‘long unsigned int’`, here -->> `if ( tel < 0 || tel >= SIZE_MAX )`

Comment: I will just stick to check `-1`.  I updated the Answer according to your Suggestions.

Comment: To avoid the warning, but not lose functionality, use `if (tel < 0 || (unsigned long) tel >= SIZE_MAX)`.

Comment: @chux Yes, I was thinking of that too, but I really HATE casts :| but I will add it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186420/discussion-between-chux-and-michi).

Comment: `(size_t) tel >= SIZE_MAX` only makes sense when `SIZE_MAX >= LONG_MAX`. C does not insure that though. `(unsigned long) tel >= SIZE_MAX` does not bring in that problem. IAC, UV for the improvement.

Comment: @chux Oh, now I see the Point, I'll update. Any way the OP asks about Linux, so I added a new Function too, which check file existence too.